# How can I add an external directory structure to my Java EE web application classpath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, oracle-adf

I am trying to set up my dev environment and we use ant script to build and deploy our application.

In my environment I have some configuration file (ADF model specific ) being created which are  external to our web container (web context). Currently we zip that external directory and put it as a jar under WEB-INF/lib. But this is a time taking process for dev.
What I want is when my web context starts up it should have that external directory structure in class path.

I am sure it can be done but what is the best way to do so. I am using weblogic.

Comment: This is vendor specific.  See if the container _you_ use can do this.

Comment: You may add your external dir path to the CLASSPATH environment variable. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the full path as a JVM property eg.

```
-DmyPath=/var/somePath
```

Then reference it from your code

```
String path = System.getProperty("myPath");
```